# SQL Server : check if property exist with true or false

Tags: sql-server, database

I am creating a login page that receives a value (string) of an email address and also has a property of email confirmed (bool). I am trying to create a stored procedure which checks if the email address that is received from the client side matches with a string value in the database. Any suggestions for this type of query?

Comment: This is a basic select statement. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I believe the confusion is because the values are coming from the client side and I have a server that references the stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.EmailAddressTable WHERE EmailAddress = @YourClientEmailAddress`

This query will return the number of rows in your table with the email address provided by the client. If you have 1 or more rows, you have a match. If you have 0 rows, you don't.

Comment: I want to use an if statement because I have a column called email confirmed needs to become true or false based on whether the column of EmailAddress has a value or not

Comment: @Dapper_Artisan how can you check false?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Email nvarchar(256)
, @EmailConfirmed bit output

as
begin 

/* 
DECLARE @EmailConfirmed bit
EXEC dbo.UserProfiles_CheckIfConfirmed 'c12@sab.com' , @EmailConfirmed OUTPUT 
SELECT @EmailConfirmed

DECLARE @EmailConfirmed bit
EXEC dbo.UserProfiles_CheckIfConfirmed 'john@sab.la' ,@EmailConfirmed OUTPUT
SELECT @EmailConfirmed
*/

SELECT @EmailConfirmed = EmailConfirmed FROM ASPNETUSERS WHERE Email = @Email

END
```

if 'john@sab.la' exists than EmailConfirmed will output a value of 1. Otherwise 0